# jquery-ui draggable inside a tab cannot be dragged outside container with overflow-y

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am having a draggable inside a tab pane, which is inside a container that is set to overflow-y: scroll. But the draggable cannot be dragged outside the container (this is required, since the drop target is outside the container!).

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="tabs">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Header</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="tabs-1">
        <div class="drag">
        </div>
        <p>Drag the pink box. It cannot go outside the gray container. If "overflow-y: scroll" is removed from its css, the box can be dragged outside.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>
        <div class="drag"></div> If the box is not inside of a tab, it can dragged outside the container.
    </p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    height: 350px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    width: 75%;
}

.drag {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: lightpink;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
$(".drag").draggable({helper: "clone"});
```

Try this at http://jsfiddle.net/79u5a/2/

In my application, I have various such containers (having overflow-y) and each containing draggables. All draggables work, except those inside of a tab.
Please let me know a solution to this.. I need to be able to drag the box-in-the-tab outside the container.

Answer (score 1):

What seems to me that your issue is `overflow-y` which you mentioned in your question, so i have a solution that if you could make another class like `.containerA{...}` but without `overflow` css property then you can do this:

### CSS:

```
.containerA {
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  width: 75%;
  /* this class without overflow property*/
}
```

### jQuery:

```
$(".drag").draggable({
   helper: "clone",
   start: function (e, ui) {
      $('.container').toggleClass('container containerA');
   },
   stop: function (e, ui) {
      $('.containerA').toggleClass('containerA container');
   }
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/79u5a/4/)

Comment: Hmm.. interesting, although changing the style will cause the layout of the page to be altered, which may not look correct. Also, I would like to know /why/ the box outside the tab works, while the one inside the doesn't?

Comment: Ummm...That may be due to js as you implemented tabs functionality to it so i think that has something which is not letting it move out.

Comment: Found the answer! On looking through the draggable api, there is an option called "appendTo", which allows you to say which element is the helper appended to. Added `appendTo: ".container"` to the draggable options and it worked like a charm!